# Negative Correlation b/w timeseries x and its future averages

Tags: time-series, correlation

We have a variable x for which we have daily data (timeseries).

It is observed x(t) is negatively correlated with Average(x(t+1)), Average(x(t+1), x(t+2)) … till Average(x(t+1), x(t+2), .. x(t+21)).

Moreover, the magnitude of negatively correlation decreases as we move towards the end of 2nd series.

I was curious on:

- Is this situation even possible?
- Can we infer something from this relation?

Comment: What is meant by "2nd series"? Can you post a plot of an example series?

Comment: 2nd series: Average(x(t+1)), Average(x(t+1), x(t+2)) … till Average(x(t+1), x(t+2), .. x(t+21))

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly possible. For a stationary AR(1) process with $\phi<0$, autocorrelation function, $\gamma(h)$, is (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/335462/475077)):

$$\gamma(h) = \phi^h\gamma(0)=\phi^h\cfrac{\sigma_w^2}{1-\phi^2}$$

You are finding $Cor(X_t, \bar{X}_{n})$, where $\bar{X}_n \equiv 1/n \sum_{i=1}^n X_{t+i}$. So what you are finding is reduced to:

\begin{align}
Cor(X_t,\bar{X}_n) &=  1/n \sum_{i=1}^n Cor(X_t,X_{t+i}) \\
&=\frac{\gamma(0)}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \phi^i 
\end{align}

So when $\phi$ is negative, $\phi^i$ will alternate is sign. When $\phi$ is negative enough, say $-0.9$ then you will get the trend you are observing, i.e., the sum will decrease in absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. Famous examples are e.g. (subsamples of) [fractional Brownian motions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Brownian_motion) with Hurst exponent less than 1/2.